# Searching for meta-values in page's metadata from functions.php

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, metadata

I created a simple newsletter page on my WP-based website. Each time someone signs up for the newsletter his e-mail address and categories he selected are stored in metadata of that page.

**Code sample from newsletter.php (it's a template):**

```
add_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'subscribed', array('email' => $_POST['email'], 'cats' => $_POST['chosenCats'], 'time' => get_the_time('d-m-Y | H:i')));
```

**Here's an example of two subscriptions stored that way:**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["email"]=>
    string(14) "agsdgeg@sdghrh"
    ["cats"]=>
    string(21) "inwestycje;targi_wyd;"
    ["time"]=>
    string(18) "23-02-2015 | 12:18"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["email"]=>
    string(10) "asfas@egeg"
    ["cats"]=>
    string(31) "produkty;katalog_firm;medycyna;"
    ["time"]=>
    string(18) "23-02-2015 | 12:18"
  }
}
```

**What do I want to do?**

1. Let's say someone subscribed for a category named "puppies".
2. Some day I add a new post to the "puppies" category.
3. My script launches in functions.php and looks for all subscriptions to that category in Newsletter's page metadata.
4. It finds required subscriptions correctly and fetches e-mail addresses from each of them.
5. It sends a notification e-mail to those people.

**What is so hard about it?**

The hardest part for me is figuring out how to browse through page's metadata while being in functions.php. Could you please help me with it?

Comment: If you know the ID of the newsletter page, you can use get_post_meta($id, 'subscribed', true) to get the post meta.

Comment: Thank you, so you confirmed that this function will work inside functions.php. What I am curious about though is whether I can somehow retrieve specific fields, like only subscriptions that contain certain categories, instead of just loading all of that metadata at once.

Comment: You would need to restructure your metadata. The way is is now, it's just a big array. The WordPress get_post_meta function does not do anything beyond just retrieving it.

Answer (score 0):

Using preg_replace_callback would be an easy hack, using regex to filter meta tags.

```
 <?php

 $html = '<meta encoding="utf-8">';
 $metadataArray = array();

 $metadata = preg_replace_callback('/\<meta\s(.*)\>/i', function($matches)
 {
    $exp = explode($matches[1]);
    $metadataArray[$exp[0]] = str_replace('"', '', $exp[1]);
 }, $html);
```

Now, you'd certainly make it better than this example, but it's a quick way of filtering out data from meta tags, assuming this is what you're looking to do.

Comment: To be honest I am not sure whether this solution is suitable for my example. Metadata that I am talking about is a WordPress functionality. You can add any information to posts and pages ("custom fields") and this information is considered metadata, as it's not really part of the content. I am looking for a way to take advantage of WP functionality to succeed with my task. Thank you though for your effort, I appreciate it :).

Comment: Gotcha, I don't know much about wordpress as I've never really liked it, so never thought of learning anything about it. However, the codex has a good doc about the get_post_meta function you mentioned. It references the get_metadata function which has examples listed. Maybe that'll help? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta